# Javascript doesn't work after call a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, canvasjs

I'm using jqwidgets for windows popout and canvasJS for charts

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#jqxwindow1 ").jqxWindow({ height:600, width: 1600, maxWidth: 1600, theme: 'fresh',autoOpen:false  });
});
```

This is the window and i make a chart which on click on label will call a java script function:

```
function onClick2(e) {
    //$('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test');
    $(document).ready(function () { /// Wait till page is loaded
        $('#main'+e.dataSeries.testcase).load('index.php?proiect=' + '<?php echo $project; ?>', function () {
            /// can add another function here
        });

    }); //// End of Wait till page is loaded
}
```

When i click on label, my main div will got the results but after that my 'show/hide' window or click on chart doesn't work anymore.

Any suggestion ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `$document.ready` inside `onClick2()`.

```
function onClick2(e) {
    //$('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test');                       
    $('#main' + e.dataSeries.testcase).load('index.php?proiect=' + '<?php echo $project; ?>', function () {
    /// can add another function here
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's half working. Now my function 'click on chart' it's working, but widget don't close/open (no one from page) after i click on chart and see some results in <div id='main'></div> so i think that script it's 'blocked' now